# node.js express using stylesheets/scripts

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I have created a web page which has the following at the start,

```
<link href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="./css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="./css/base-admin-3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/base-admin-3-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./compiled/flipclock.css">
<link href="./css/pages/plans.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="./css/pages/pricing.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script src="./compiled/flipclock.js"></script>

<link href="./css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have the page created statically and it looks perfect, however now I have started to integrate it with node.js and express. When loading the page from the app.js I am using.
`app.get('/liveSale.html', function(req, res){
        res.sendfile('liveSale.html');
 });`

However when the page is loaded it will not render the stylesheets and scripts.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using `res.sendfile`, why not `res.render()`

Comment: I was just working directly of the http://socket.io chat client example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a couple of duplicate threads.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Yep, exactly.  Without the static middleware set up, Express won't automatically serve files from anywhere.  Hypothetically you could set up separate `app.get('/your-js-file.js')` calls that sends the file, but usually `express.static()` is the way to go.